# FullpageJS how to go directory to specific section with animation but without showing sections in-between

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I apologize in advance if this question is repetitive but could not find an answer else where.

So I am building a site upon JS plugin called fullpageJS.

I know the basic setup of fullpageJS, but is there any option that goes directory to the specific section with sliding animation but without showing the in-between sections when using navigation. 
Do I have to tweak a little? (I know silent move option but it just goes directory to the specified section with no animation.)

For example:
I have 4 sections in my page and currently showing section 1. When I click the #3 button in the navigation, it will go from section 1 to section 3 without seeing section 2 and vice-versa.

- Section 1 // go from here
- Section 2 // -- don't want to see u!
- Section 3 // to here
- Section 4

Comment: I tried hiding the element which I want to skip in onLeave callback(before scroll start) but the animation was corrupted. Because the scroll distance looks like based on section height (or view height).

Comment: Question is. Why would you want a section in between if you'll never show it?

Comment: @Alvaro Actually I want this feature only when I use navigation or menu buttons. For the mouse scroll, I do not want sections to be skipped. I want to see them sequentially, like 1->2(i want to see u here!)->3->4.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible by the way fullPage.js works.

Comment: @Alvaro thanks. So I ended up making my own script for the project for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party.
But the following thing works.

```
/*Scrolling to the section with the anchor link `firstSlide` and to the 2nd Slide */
fullpage_api.silentMoveTo('firstSlide', 2);
```

[Doc links](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#silentmovetosection-slide)